# ImageView inside recyclerView width and height layout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview

I have a chat application like whatsapp. I want to show several images that i have in the internal storage. So the only thing that i know for that image is the path that i can find it.
However, in the xml layout of the image_item i must set the width and height of the imageView.

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rcvImage"
            android:layout_width="280dp"
            android:layout_height="280dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="320dp"
            android:maxHeight="320dp"
            android:minWidth="150dp"
            android:minHeight="150dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/default_img"
            tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />
```

How can i set the values so i can have portrait and landscape images, but without making lags in the recyclerview scrolling

Comment: Have you use Glide or Picasso? https://github.com/bumptech/glide

Comment: i use Glide. But i am talking about the width and height that i should set in the layout. Not the way that i will show the image

Answer (score 0):

You can set `wrap_content` and also `adjustViewBounds`

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:src="@drawable/test"/>
```

Also, scaleType can help with the image resize

```
android:scaleType="fitStart"
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType

Comment: I want one side to be always 280dp. If it is a Portrait then i want (width, 280), else if it is landscape i want (280, height)

Comment: so just set your height and width attributes programmatically inside the activity for different picture sizes.